# Безопасно ли сравнивать переменные с присвоенными значениями константы между собой?

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
const double Pi = 3.14;
double a = Pi;
double b = Pi;
```

кода типа:

```
double x = 3.;
double b = (4.0 - x) * Pi;
```

в программе быть *не может*, т.е. всегда идет присваивание `var = Pi`.

Корректно ли в этом (и только в этом) случае сравнивать `a == b`?

Чуть добавлю. Присвение константы в программе может выглядеть примерно так:

```
double b = some_expression;
if (b < Pi + epsilon && Pi - epsilon < b) b = Pi;
```

И никак иначе.

П.С. Использвание числа, похожего на математическое "пи" - только для примера, к реальности отношения не имеет.

Попробуем сформулировать вопрос более широко. Есть две строки кода, идущие подряд.

```
double x = some_value;
double y = x;
// not double y = some_expression_that_equal_to_x;
```

Типы `x`, `y` одинаковые, это важно. Гарантированно ли одинаковое двоичное представление `x` и `y`?

Comment: сорри опечатался, поправил

Comment: А как вы можете гарантировать, что `b` никогда не станет равным `Pi` в результате каких-либо других действий?

Comment: а вот интересный вариант http://ideone.com/EOmPrO :)

Comment: @KoVadim, целые числа до 2^53 представляются в double точно.

Comment: @KromStern А я никогда не сравниваю таким образом случайную переменную с константой. Только если я знаю, что значение переменной уставлено кодом из последнего отрывка.

Comment: @Qwertiy а где в моем примере целые числа?

Comment: @KoVadim что показывает Ваш пример? что это равенство *может быть* истинным? Это и так понятно... Может быть, а может и не быть, если 4-3 заменить на что-то менее тривиальное.

Comment: вот как раз я и хотел показать то, что может быть равным (то, что в вопросе неявно предполагалось, что может быть не равным).

Comment: @KoVadim, 4 - целое, 3 - целое, 4-3=1 тоже целое. Если число целое и оно не превосходит 2^53 по модулю, то оно представимо в double без потери точности, что означает, что в любых операциях с такими числами (при условии, что результат тоже является таким числом) можно использовать проверку на равенство. Ну а уж умножить на 1 скорее всего тоже можео без проблем. Да и вообще, компилятор мог всю эту арифметику выпилить и оставить присваивание.

Comment: 4 - целое, 4. - нет. Но компилятор не идиот и понимает, что это все можно сократить. В скомпилированном коде будет просто вызов puts.

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос, автор же пишет, что он `(4-3) *` никогда делать не будет

Comment: @KoVadim, я говорю не о типе данных, а о фактическом значении. Все 3 числа (4., 3., 4.-3.) будут представлены точно. Т. е. даже если дело дойдёт до умножения (в чём я сильно сомневаюсь), там будет умножаться точная единица на некое число. Я _почти_ уверен, что такая операция будет давать точный результат.

Comment: @KoVadim, `"В скомпилированном коде будет просто вызов puts"` -- это если компилировать с оптимизацией (даже все переменные и константу выбрасывает). Без нее gcc, например, честно проводит все вычисления (и кстати, .`pi != b` !!!)

Comment: А переменные с заведомо равными значениями сравнивать можно.

Comment: Хм, интересно, а как вы себе представляете работу компьютера который *не гарантирует* точное двоичное представление при копировании? :D

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, тут просто дело в разном количестве разрядов в памяти (double -- 64bit) и регистре FPU (80bit)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, при копировании-то гарантирует. Но вот компилятор, а точнее оптимизатор, может это копирование выпилить. Тогда окажется, что нечто более точное сравнивается с ним же, но урезанным до double. Возможна ли такая ситуация именно при копировании, я не знаю. Но пример, когда такое происходило при вычислении - был. Дважды считается одно и то же и сравнивается на равенство. Первое вычисление компилятор приводит к double, а второе остаётся в long double и сравнение говорит, что значения различны.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, при вычислении вопросов нет. Поэтому например при `double a = 3.14; a == 3.14; (-> false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на более "широкий" вопрос. Да, одинаковое двоичное представление гарантировано. Без вариантов. В противном случае (помимо просто абсурдности) были бы возможны всякие интересные штуки например, при:

```
double a = 3.14;
```

операция

```
a = a;
```

меняла бы двоичное представление `a`.

Comment: Опять же, если можно, ссыдку на пруф. Просто, если это так, то `a=x; b=x` гарантирует одинаковое двоичное представление `a` и `b`, а это вроде как ответ на первый вопрос, разве нет?

Comment: @andy.37, в том виде, как у Вас написан код в вопросе (т.е. никаких *вычислений* с `a` и `b` нет и константа не является *константным  выражением* (т.е. не вычисляется)) можете смело их сравнивать.

Comment: @andy.37 не совсем понятно, что вам нужно в качестве пруфа. Т.е. сложно искать доказательства около-аксиомных вещей. Т.е. аналогичное утверждение для `int` вам не кажется оспоримым, а для `double` - кажется. Я не вижу между ними различия. Приведите пруф для `int`, я думаю пруф для `double` будет где-то рядом. И да, логично что ответ на более широкий вопрос подтверждает частный случай.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, если Вы сравниваете значения *в памяти*, то разницы нет. А если результат вычислений с памятью, то есть, поскольку размер целочисленных регистров совпадает с размером этих переменных в памяти, а вот регистров с плавающей точкой -- нет. Т.е. возможна ситуация, когда компилятор видит, что один из операндов сравнения все еще в регистре и повторно не загружает в него значение из памяти (а на самом деле при записи в память несколько бит урезались). Поэтому и возникает проблема о которой тут и разговорились.

Comment: @avp не вижу как размер регистра влияет на два числа загруженных из памяти. Если я все правильно понял вопрос речь не идёт о вычисленных значениях.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, правильно, для конкретного кода в вопросе не влияет (я уже написал это выше).

Answer (score 4):

Если компилятор случайно подставит константу в выражение как `long double`, а переменная будет `double`, то неожиданно окажется, что они всё-таки не равны. Так что лучше не надо, если только ты не стопроцентно уверен, что твоя константа точно представима в типе double.

Comment: Но ведь приведение типа так или иначе будет производится 1 раз, при определении `const`, разве нет? Дальше `Pi` имеет вполне определенное (и неизменяющееся в дальнейшем) двоичное представление, да, зависящее от архитектуры машины и, возможно, от компилятора, но одинаковое везде в скомпилированной программе. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @andy.37, погугли код, где есть переменная `double x` с некоторым значением и код `if (sin(x) != sin(x))` - там с ассемблерным листингом разобрано, что левый sin после вычисления приводится из `long double` в `double`, а правый остаётся в `long double`, после чего при сравнении оказывается, что значения не равны. Если компилятор по такой же логике заинлайнит константу, причём в `long double`, то она уже может оказаться не равна своему округлённому до `double` значению.

Comment: спасибо за ценные (без иронии) комментарии. Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что в моем прмере `sizeof Pi` не обязано быть равно `sizeof(double)`? Еще раз, я никогда не сравниваю `sin(Pi) == sin(Pi)`, я сравниваю только `var == Pi` и только после явного `var=Pi`.

Comment: @andy.37, там была фишка в том, что компилятор по какой-то причине пропускал приведение - какая-то оптимизация. Я не знаю, как он заинлайнит константу. По идее, для кода не должно быть видимо то, что делает компилятор. Но мало ли что там получится. Если твоя константа `2` или даже `11111.875` - сравнивай сколько хочешь. Если `3.1` - я бы на всякий случай не стал.

Comment: Если Вы сравнивате var == Pi и только после явного var=Pi, тогда скорее всего у Вас проблема в дизайне кода - нужно использовать буленовскую переменную. И никаких проблем.

Comment: @andy.37, для обновлённого вопроса. Компилятор умеет оптимизировать. Он может нечто убрать. Однако, если присваивание _действительно выполнилось_, то они должны быть равны. Подвох в том, что оно могло не выполниться.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы уходите от прямого ответа на вопрос)). Я так понимаю, ответ - нет? (я понимаю приведенные Вами причины такого ответа).

Comment: @andy.37, я не знаю. Я предполагаю, что ответ да. А если вдруг окажется нет, то это скорее баг компилятора. Но я не могу гарантировать, что это действительно так.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за конструктивный диалог

Comment: @andy.37, если в самом деле боитесь, что одним из операндов сравнения вместо переменной окажется регистр FPU (а не его значение ранее выгруженное в память), то объявите эти ваши перменные с атрибутом volatile.

Comment: @avp, это сильнее навредит производительности.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, если эта дурь будет где-то во вложенных циклах. Но вряд ли производительность просядет меньше при сравнениях с эпсилоном или внутри неоптимизированной (там точно переменные окажутся в памяти перед сравнением) функции.

Comment: А может проще всего посмотреть на генерируемый компайлером код.

Comment: @avp, на хабре была статья, где сравнение строк с volatile для содержимого работало в 10 (а может и 20 - не помню точно) раз медленнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, пусть ТС сравнит на своей задаче и доложит.

Comment: Все случаи, когда мы пытаемся опираться на то, что «значение будет вычислено только один раз»  и т. п. обычно приводят к компиляторозависимому коду.

Comment: По теме: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24446382/276994